# How to reconcile two different intuitions of the Laplacian operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In [here](https://youtu.be/4J74tquQ7jU?t=435) the Laplacian $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ is said to:

> The Laplacian measures the degree by which the value at a point differs from the average of its neighbors.

whereas [here](https://youtu.be/EW08rD-GFh0?t=278) the intuition departs from a more stringent set up: there is a scalar-valued function $f(x,y),$ from which the Laplacian is defined as the divergence of the gradient, $\nabla\cdot\nabla f.$ The intuition is:

> A measure of how much of a minimum a point is in a scalar valued multivariate function.

The question is where the **average** appears in the first interpretation - is it truly the average as understood in statistics? Because the second derivative in different directions seems to directly speak about the curvature of the graph - there is no averaging.

And is the gradient also implied in the first interpretation? Or there is no real need for a gradient to understand the Laplacian?

Comment: Use the finite difference formulation to see the averaging. Using $h$ to denote the fixed step size in both directions \begin{align} 0 &= \Delta u \\ &\to \frac{u^{i+1}_{j} + u^{i-1}_{j} + u^{i}_{j+1} + u^{i}_{j-1} - 4u^{i}_{j}}{h^{2}} \\ \implies u^{i}_{j} &= \frac{u^{i+1}_{j} + u^{i-1}_{j} + u^{i}_{j+1} + u^{i}_{j-1}}{4} \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the square centered at $(0,0)$ with coordinates $(\pm h,\pm h)$.
Average the value of $u$ at these four corners and measure the difference from $u(0,0)$:
$$
    \frac{u(h,h) + u(-h,h) + u(h,-h) + u(-h,-h)}{4} - u(0,0)
    = \frac{u(h,h) + u(-h,h) + u(h,-h) + u(-h,-h) - 4u(0,0)}{4}
$$
by Taylor's theorem, 
\begin{align*}
    u(h,h) &= u(0,0) + h u_x(0,0) + h u_y(0,0) + \frac{1}{2}h^2(u_{xx}(0,0) + 2u_{xy}(0,0) + u_{yy}(0,0)) +R(h,h) \\\\
    u(h,-h) &= u(0,0) + h u_x(0,0) - h u_y(0,0) + \frac{1}{2}h^2(u_{xx}(0,0) - 2u_{xy}(0,0) + u_{yy}(0,0)) +R(h,-h) \\\\ 
    u(-h,h) &= u(0,0) - h u_x(0,0) + h u_y(0,0) + \frac{1}{2}h^2(u_{xx}(0,0) - 2u_{xy}(0,0) + u_{yy}(0,0)) +R(-h,h) \\\\
    u(-h,-h) &= u(0,0) + h u_x(0,0) - h u_y(0,0) + \frac{1}{2}h^2(u_{xx}(0,0) + 2u_{xy}(0,0) + u_{yy}(0,0)) +R(-h,-h) \\\\ 
\end{align*}
You see that if we add these four together,
$$
\frac{u(h,h) + u(-h,h) + u(h,-h) + u(-h,-h) - 4u(0,0)}{4}
= h^2 \left(u_{xx}(0,0)+u_yy(0,0)\right) + \text{remainders}
$$
So
$$
   \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(h,h) + u(-h,h) + u(h,-h) + u(-h,-h) - 4u(0,0)}{4h^2} = \nabla^2 u(0,0)
$$